# How do I make changes to a resource/dynamic segment from a nested route?

Tags: ember.js

If a user was looking on airbnb, and they inputted their 'check-in' date, how would I persist that information in the URL as they go through searching for a house and booking it?

I was thinking that the best way to achieve this would be to have an outer resource, `user_data`. All of the data that makes up the `user_data` resource would be kept in a dynamic segment.

But, I am not sure how I would make changes to the `user_data` resource (and the dynamic segment) from any of the nested resources and routes.

Here is my router map:

```
MockAirbnb.Router.map ->
  @route 'index',{ path: '/' }
  @resource 'user_data', { path: '/:user_data'}, ->
    @route 'search', { path: '/search'}
    @resource 'house',{ path: '/:house_id'}, ->
      @resource 'booking',{ path: '/booking'}
```

**Bonus question:**

How would I make an immediate change to the :`user_data` resource by choosing a new date in the booking page? (changing url on form input event without appearing to change the view)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a binding on your nested controllers to the UserDataController.  Something like this:

```
App.BookingController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: 'userData',
    checkInDateBinding: 'controllers.userData.checkInDate'
});
```

Your data model seems a little awkward, but that should do it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply-- I will try it out!

I am just getting into Ember and would love it if you explained what makes the data model seem awkward.